# Loop N table columns and insert concatenated string into same row

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a string list with concatenated value separated by delimiter like this:

```
DECLARE @stringlist NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'company_no,emp_no,emp_name,emp_type,salary_type....'
```

And I have a temp table with dynamic number of nameless columns with following data:

```
------------------------------
001   A01   John  P     A
001   A05   Mary  P     A
```

I want to split the string and insert each split string into each column in one row, such as below:

```
-----------------------------------------------
company_no emp_no emp_name emp_type salary_type
001        A01    John     P        A
001        A05    Mary     P        A
```

I can split the string into multiple rows. But how do I split and loop each column in temp table to insert these value?

Comment: What do you mean by temp table with nameless columns? Columns must have names.

Comment: Do you mean the `@stringlist` variable holds the eventual column names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming by your sample data and desired result that all columns in the destination table are some string type, I would suggest not to split the string at all.
Instead, create a dynamic sql insert statement from it:

```
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max);
SET @Sql = 'INSERT INTO <TempTableNameHere> 
            VALUES ('''+ REPLACE(@stringList, ',', ''',''') + ''');';

EXEC(@Sql);
```

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci we all over complicate things sometimes. That's why I like [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) so much.

Comment: Awesome! After many hours of cracking my header trying to loop every column & every row.... couldn't believe the solution can be so simple once we think a little different

Comment: Sometimes all you need is diffrrent approach... Glad to help ;-)